# Passing Variable From PHP Function to AJAX in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am currently working on a custom widget for Elementor and need to convert my Javascript functions into Ajax functions. My main issue has been figuring out how to pass variables from PHP to AJAX.

Here is the Javascript for the function in Question:

```
    //Dynamic Price Calculator

      $('#productQuant').keyup(function(){

        // assign size from checked radio button
        let productSize =  $("input[type=radio][name=sizeRadio]:checked" ).val();
        // assign quantity from values found in input text box
        let productQuantity = $("#productQuant").val();

        $.ajax({
            // admin-ajax.php url
             url: productDataAjax.url,
             method: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             data:({
               action: 'priceUpdate',
               phpProductSize: productSize,
               phpProductQuantity: productQuantity

             }),

             success:function(data){
             console.log("Success");
             // Text to product total
              $('#productTotal').text(" " + data.dynamicTotal);
             }

           });


         }); // function end
})( jQuery );
```

Here is the PHP:

```
    /* Enque Scripts and Styles */

function shop_plugin_assets(){

  // Enqueue CSS

  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

// remeber array(), null at the end to mak sure googlefonts load. family = family = etc throws it off
  wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee&family=Sintony&display=swap', array(), null );



  // Enqueue JQuery and JS Files

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-bundle-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );

     wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js-custom/my-scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


     $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        );

        wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'productDataAjax', $script_data_array);

    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shop_plugin_assets', 20 );


function dynamicPriceCalc(){

                 $productSize = $_POST['phpProductSize'];
                 $productQuantity =  $_POST['phpProductQuantity'];
                 $productPrice = 0;
                 $productTotal = 0;
                 $response = array();

                 if( $productSize === "small"){
                     $productPrice = 7.99;
                     $productTotal = number_format( (float) ($productPrice * $productQuantity), 2, '.', '');

                     $response["dynamicTotal"] = $productTotal;
                     echo json_encode($response);

                 }
                 else if( $productSize === "medium"){

                     $productPrice = 10.99;
                     $productTotal = number_format( (float) ($productPrice * $productQuantity), 2, '.', '');
                     $response["dynamicTotal"] = $productTotal;
                     echo json_encode($response);


                 }
                 else if( $productSize === "large"){
                     $productPrice = 14.99;
                     $productTotal = number_format( (float) ($productPrice * $productQuantity), 2, '.', '');
                     $response["dynamicTotal"] = $productTotal;
                     echo json_encode($response);

                 }



                     die();

                 }


                 add_action('wp_ajax_priceUpdate', 'dynamicPriceCalc');
                 add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_priceUpdate', 'dynamicPriceCalc');
```

Here is the Elementor widget File:

```
<?php
class Elementor_Custom_Product_Archive_Food extends \Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'Custom Product Archive Food';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return esc_html__( 'Custom Product Archive Food Service', 'elementor-addon' );
    }

    public function get_icon() {
        return 'eicon-code';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ 'basic' ];
    }

    public function get_keywords() {
        return [ 'archive', 'product', 'food' ];
    }


// Controls for widgets



    protected function register_controls()

  {
        $this->start_controls_section(
        'button_section',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Product Archive Food', 'custom_product_archive_food' ),
            'tab' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
        ]
    );

    $this->add_control(
        'button_align',
        [
            'label' => esc_html__( 'Alignment', 'custom_product_archive_food' ),
            'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::CHOOSE,
            'options' => [

                'text-start' => [
                    'title' => esc_html__( 'Left', 'custom_product_archive_food' ),
                    'icon' => 'eicon-text-align-left',
                ],
                'text-center' => [
                    'title' => esc_html__( 'Center', 'custom_product_archive_food' ),
                    'icon' => 'eicon-text-align-center',
                ],
                'text-end' => [
                    'title' => esc_html__( 'Right', 'custom_product_archive_food' ),
                    'icon' => 'eicon-text-align-right',
                ],
            ],
            'default' => 'text-center',
            'toggle' => true,
        ]
    );

    $this->end_controls_section();


  } //end of controls




// Render the HTML and pulll data from controls to change classes or feed settings dynamic properties

protected function render() {
        // settings pulls properties from control options to use within your html blocks
        $settings = $this->get_settings_for_display();
        $checkOutLink = wc_get_checkout_url();

    // Radio Size selector
    echo '<div class="text-center my-2">';
    echo '<label>  Choose a Size </label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="text-center mt-2" id="radioContainer">';
          echo '<div class="form-check-inline">';
          echo '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sizeRadio" id="smallRadio" value="small">';
          echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="smallRadio">';
          echo 'Small';
          echo '</label>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="form-check-inline">';
          echo '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sizeRadio" id="medRadio" value="medium">';
          echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="medRadio">';
          echo 'Medium';
          echo '</label>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<div class="form-check-inline">';
          echo '<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sizeRadio" id="largeRadio" value="large">';
          echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="largeRadio">';
          echo 'Large';
          echo '</label>';
          echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    // Quantity / Logic Button / Redirect Button';
       echo '<div class="text-center">';
       echo '<div class="my-2">';
          echo '<label id="productPrice"> Price: </label>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<input type="text" class="form-control input-group mt-3 w-25 mx-auto" placeholder="Enter Quantity" aria-label="Quantity" id="productQuant">';
          echo '<div class="my-2">';
          echo '<label id="productTotal"> Total:</label>';
          echo '</div>';
          echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning m-3 " name="button" id="addCartSubmit"> Add to Cart </button>';
          echo '<a href="'.$checkOutLink.'" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning m-3"> Proceed to Check Out</a>';
        echo '</div>';



} // End of protected functions


} //end of class
```

It is my understanding that I am supposed to call the PHP function using action while sending whatever data I pull with JQuery, execute the PHP function, make an array of the result within that function, encode the result in JSON, and on success have the JSON data inserted into whatever JQuery function I need it for.

For some reason, the function won't work even after trying several variations of the solution seen above. I know the logic works as I've recreated the same solution with pure JQuery and it works without a hitch. I know that there is some type of response going through as I get undefined and a console log of success when I remove the dataType:'json'. I don't know what is happening in between these two things that is stopping me from getting the label change to reflect my new product total.

Some Images After Inputting Text into the Text Field. You'll notice the Total section remains blank:

[Header Request showing it accepts Javascript and JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li9wD.png)

[Preview Showing HTML page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1skVT.jpg)

[Response showing HTML - I think I need it to return JSON here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs0wd.png)

[Payload Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EU4N.png)

Comment: There is a typo  add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ppriceUpdate', 'dynamicPriceCalc')   (the double 'p')  If you are getting '0' as the response of your ajax call, then mostly this is the problem.

Comment: Please confirm if the typo correction solved the issue or not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed the typo but still no response. My console remains blank when I keypress on the input field.

Comment: Please check your network tab in chrome developer tools and select Fetch/XHR and then type and check if you're sending any requests or not. because I am suspecting, that DOM is not loading on page load so your `$('#productQuant').keyup(function` won't work in that case, you'll have to change it to `$(document).on( 'keyup', '#productQuant', function` then it will work.

Comment: I think it's working. I never used Fetch/XHR before but when I brought it up on the Chrome Developer tools I got a status 200 response with a green line next to it. Each time I typed into the input it I got the same kind of response. I will try document.on anyway couldn't hurt. I am developing this using Local Wordpress by the way. Would that have any bearing on this?

Comment: As @VijayHardaha said. Make sure that your javascript is embedded after the DOM Element in question. To check it you can do a console.log($('#productQuant')) just before the keyup binding and see if the element is getting selected or not.

Comment: You can click on your request then you'll find the header, payload, response, and preview tabs, check the response or preview tab and check what you're getting in response.

Comment: It looks like I am getting the right element targeted. I tried typing in the number 9 in the input field. I got a status 200, the header says it accepts javascript,  the payload was the number 9 ( exactly what I typed). The response seems odd. The response is just my entire html for the page.

Comment: You can try to return json response without checking any if else and debug the things step by step. Your JS is working, now you need to debug your ajax response.

Comment: @VijayHardaha That sounds like a good idea. I'll try to make a simplified version I can pick apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core issue was that I was not using the right name for my ajax url. In my case, the object declared in my functions.php needed to be written as productUpdate.ajaxUrl for my ajax url to have the correct url to follow. I thought I needed to write it as just productUpdate.url.

For reference this is where the array and the object were declared in functions.php:

```
function shop_plugin_assets(){

  // Enqueue CSS

  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

// remeber array(), null at the end to mak sure googlefonts load. family = family = etc throws it off
  wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee&family=Sintony&display=swap', array(), null );



  // Enqueue JQuery and JS Files

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-bundle-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );

     wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js-custom/my-scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


     $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('product_nonce')
        );

        wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'productDataAjax', $script_data_array);

    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shop_plugin_assets', 20 );
```

This is the what the proper ajax function looks like:

```
$('#productQuant').keyup(function(){

        // assign size from checked radio button
        let productSize =  $("input[type=radio][name=sizeRadio]:checked" ).val();
        // assign quantity from values found in input text box
        let productQuantity = $("#productQuant").val();

        $.ajax({
            // admin-ajax.php url
             url: productDataAjax.ajaxUrl,
             method: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             data:({

              action: 'priceUpdate',
              phpProductSize: productSize,
              phpProductQuantity: productQuantity,
               _ajax_nonce: productDataAjax.nonce

             }),

             success:function(response){

             console.log("success");
             //Text to product total
             $('#productTotal').text(" " + response.dynamicTotal);
             }

           });


         }); // function end
})( jQuery );
```

This is the full code after all changes have been made:

Functions.php

```
/* Enque Scripts and Styles */

function shop_plugin_assets(){

  // Enqueue CSS

  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all' );

// remeber array(), null at the end to mak sure googlefonts load. family = family = etc throws it off
  wp_enqueue_style( 'google-font', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee&family=Sintony&display=swap', array(), null );



  // Enqueue JQuery and JS Files

  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-bundle-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );

     wp_enqueue_script( 'my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js-custom/my-scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );


     $script_data_array = array(
        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('product_nonce')
        );

        wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'productDataAjax', $script_data_array);

    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shop_plugin_assets', 20 );


function dynamicPriceCalc(){

                check_ajax_referer('product_nonce');

                 $productSize = $_POST['phpProductSize'];
                 $productQuantity =  $_POST['phpProductQuantity'];
                 $productPrice = 0;
                 $productTotal = 0;
                 $response = array();


                 if( $productSize === "small"){
                     $productPrice = 7.99;
                     $productTotal = number_format( (float) ($productPrice * $productQuantity), 2, '.', '');

                     // stor return values in an array
                     $response["dynamicTotal"] = $productTotal;
                     // returns variables to ajax function making the call
                     echo json_encode($response);
                    // wp_ die() better for wordpress rather than just die()
                        wp_die();


                 }
                 else if( $productSize === "medium"){

                     $productPrice = 10.99;
                     $productTotal = number_format( (float) ($productPrice * $productQuantity), 2, '.', '');

                     // stor return values in an array
                     $response["dynamicTotal"] = $productTotal;
                     // returns variables to ajax function making the call
                     echo json_encode($response);
                    // wp_ die() better for wordpress rather than just die()
                        wp_die();

                 }
                 else if( $productSize === "large"){
                     $productPrice = 14.99;
                     $productTotal = number_format( (float) ($productPrice * $productQuantity), 2, '.', '');

                     // stor return values in an array
                     $response["dynamicTotal"] = $productTotal;
                     // returns variables to ajax function making the call
                     echo json_encode($response);
                    // wp_ die() better for wordpress rather than just die()
                        wp_die();
                 }


                 }


                 add_action('wp_ajax_priceUpdate', 'dynamicPriceCalc');
                 add_action('wp_ajax_priceUpdate', 'dynamicPriceCalc');
```

Javascipt File

```
$('#productQuant').keyup(function(){

        // assign size from checked radio button
        let productSize =  $("input[type=radio][name=sizeRadio]:checked" ).val();
        // assign quantity from values found in input text box
        let productQuantity = $("#productQuant").val();

        $.ajax({
            // admin-ajax.php url
             url: productDataAjax.ajaxUrl,
             method: 'post',
             dataType: 'json',
             data:({

              action: 'priceUpdate',
              phpProductSize: productSize,
              phpProductQuantity: productQuantity,
               _ajax_nonce: productDataAjax.nonce

             }),

             success:function(response){

             console.log("success");
             //Text to product total
             $('#productTotal').text(" " + response.dynamicTotal);
             }

           });


         }); // function end
})( jQuery );
```

The nonce was just added for some extra security. It has nothing to do with the actual solution. I'd like to thank everyone again who pitched in to help me fix this issue. Now I can get back to converting the rest of my Javascript into Ajax.